# How to read my old deleted iPhone WhatsApp messages from PC/Mac?

Tags: iphone, data-recovery, whatsapp.app

I deleted some important messages seven days ago and want to recover them. How can I undo my mistake and how can I read the data from my PC/Mac?

Comment: where were they before you deleted them? If not on that device, then unlikely.

Comment: i deleted that from my iphone

Comment: Probably gone, then, unless you can somehow access online. Data deleted from a hardware encrypted device is really gone.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try logging into [WhatsApp for Mac?](https://www.whatsapp.com/download/)

Comment: i tried... those message is not there

Comment: A feature of whatsapp is that it's super encrypted. Not sure if there's anything you can do